# Debugging with no errors or warning

Tags: jquery, debugging, safari, flickr

I'm making a site that works flawless in Chrome and Firefox. But in Safari it doesn't work. But there is no errors or warnings in my console. Where do i start ?

Does not work in Safari 5.0.5(mac) and IE9.

I think the problem is in the script that loads in from Flickr.

http://aalborguni.jonasjonasjonas.dk/arkiktektonisk-mestervaerk/ - check it out if you got the time :)

Comment: javascript problem I suspect. very strange, maybe some conflict with libraries or plugins in safari only?

Comment: I just had a look in IE9 and the same problem exists in that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i found the answer to this stupid bug.

The problem was that the orbit-script was initialized before the flickr-script. And therefore it was not able to determine the width/height of the image.

In this case i found a simple solution by hardcoding the height/width into the flickr-loader - and the initializing Orbit once that was done.

Thanks  for all of your help!

Answer (score 2):

What exactly doesn't work? Is this Mac or Win? Version of Safari? A little more information would help with a resolution.

In theory both Chrome and Safari are Webkit-based browsers (although slightly differetn versions) and should be very similar in operation, although Chrome uses the V8 JS engine and Safari doesn't.

I would start by using the Safari JS debugger and stepping through the code and querying the variables etc and see if anything jumps out at you.

A little more information on differences between the two are shown in this question:

[Does Google Chrome display pages the same as Safari?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/179512/does-google-chrome-display-pages-the-same-as-safari)

Also more information on the different JS Engines:

[JavaScript Engines](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JavaScript_engine)

Comment: Updated the question now. Thanks for the links - really helpful for future debugging to!

Answer (score 1):

I debugged it with winSafari and get

```
Unmatched </p> encountered.  Converting </p> into <p></p>. line 115 ---p>
```

---

```
    Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry&#8217;s standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.</p>
</div>
<p>&nbsp;</p>
</p> <-- ERROR
             </div>
         </div>
```

I don't know if it is this though.. because javascript is not loading. but maybe?!
#
I don't think it is the

- but fix that any way- There is a problem with your STYLING?!

When the page load its

```
<div id="featured" class="orbit" style="height: 1px; width: 1px;
```

The images are there and loaded but for some reason its not styling. So again.. the plugin inst working properly-0 try removing every thing except jquery and the oribit- or try a test page stand alone simple in safari.

[image: Safari]

So the script ends prematurely because no cycling is happening.

Comment: I checked it out. And i can get the images into every other div than the div#featured... I have no idea why! When i ask the script to append to "body" or ".post" it works. But when i ask for #featured is does nuttin'!

Comment: It works on every other page to. It's only when im combining a multiload from flickr into Orbit. But yes, the problem is that it sets height/width to be 0px... And i have no idea why.

Comment: well its in IE9 and Safari. which is an un usaul combination for an error to occur. Usually its IE or Chrome/Safari not a mixture. I can only suggest you keep stripping your code down until it works.. and try and determine from there what is causing a clash. no errors are generated so its difficult to debug.

Comment: It's driving me crazy :) So don't hestitate with inputs! :)

Answer (score 0):

The comma after "bullets: true," seems wrong to me.

```
$(window).load(function() {
    $('#featured').orbit({
     animation: 'horizontal-push',      // fade, horizontal-slide, vertical-slide, horizontal-push
     timer: true,            // true or false to have the timer
     advanceSpeed: 8000,         // if timer is enabled, time between transitions 
     pauseOnHover: true,
     startClockOnMouseOut: true,     // if clock should start on MouseOut
     bullets: true,      // true or false to activate the bullet navigation
    });
```

Comment: I think the problem is in the Flickr-script somewhere :)